# Customize rails i18n per tenant using postgre schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm using the [Apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) to switch into a postgre schema for each request in our app. When the tenant is found, I set the locale based on a database field:

```
I18n.locale = current_tenant.locale || I18n.default_locale
```

This works great for switching languages. Now I have a request from a customer to change a single key in the yml file. I'd like to give our customers a database-driven way to override certain keys, but I'm not sure how to set up the I18n backend to override individual keys. I could use the [active_record gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record), but this stores the translations globally, so if I override for one tenant, it overrides for all.

I think I need a way to preload the translations and look them up by tenant subdomain instead of language. All the methods I've found seem to be doing the backend loading in an initializer, not per request, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

By "override certain keys", do you mean the value of the keys?

If so, one way to achieve this is by storing overrides in the database, in a table -- let's call it -- `custom_overrides`.

This table would have attributes: `id`, `user_id`, `key_name`, `locale`, `expansion_string`, and others like timestamps.

**Modification:**

When a customer wants to modify a key's value with `key_name`, "okn", you would create a new record in the `custom_overrides` table.

**Reading keys:**

When you read the key, "okn" instead of doing

```
t(:okn)
```

you would do:

```
CustomOverride.where(
  :key_name => :okn,
  :locale => config.locale,
  :user_id => current_user.id
).first.try(:expansion_string) 
  ||
  t(:okn)
```

That is to say, always perform a database read to determine whether the `key_name` is in it defined by the `current_user`, if not only then fall-back to i18n.

You could end up having keys in the production databases that you have become obsolete. You would have to reconcile the `locale.yml` files with the `custom_overrides` table (e.g. run migrations periodically to remove entries in `custom_overrides` whose `key_name`s are not in the `en.yml` file.)

Comment: This is what https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record does, which is what I'm hoping to avoid. I'm looking at preloading all the translations per tenant and overriding the default "Simple" i18n backend with those.